# When is the copy constructor for the return value happens

Tags: c++, return, language-lawyer

I have the following member function:

```
Person ClassB::DoSomethingAndReturnPerson()
{
 RAIIMutex myLock(&m_mutex);
 return m_person;
}
```

`RAIIMutex` is an helper class that recieves a mutex and locks it in the constructor and releases in the destructor.

`m_person` is of type `Person` (something very small in size). Other functions in other threads might change this member.

I want to return `m_person` by value (return a copy) and of course I want to avoid the situation where the `m_person` being changed in another thread while it's being copied in the return so I've added the lock.

But what happens first ? Does the compiler first creates a copy of `m_person` or first calls the destructor of `myLock` ?

Theoretically it easly solvable by doing something like this :

```
Person ClassB::DoSomethingAndReturnPerson()
{
 RAIIMutex myLock(&m_mutex);
 Person tmp = m_person;
 return tmp;
}
```

But I'm interested in knowing the answer to my question.

Thanks

Comment: [OT] You can replace `RAIIMutex` with [`std::lock_gurad`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: The copy constructor may not be called at all, due to [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is doubtful as `m_person` appears to be a class member variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The copy-initialization of the returned value will be processed before.

From the standard, [[stmt.return]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#3) (emphasis mine)

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call is sequenced before
>   the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression
>   established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, **is
>   sequenced before the destruction of local variables ([stmt.jump]) of
>   the block enclosing the return statement**.

Comment: Thanks, Where can I find the standard ? Is it available for free ?

Comment: @OopsUser You might want to see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents), or [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3309790), basically, the [final draft before standardization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) is more than adequate (and free).

Answer (score -1):

Destructors of local objects are called after 'the last line of your code'. Here is a relevant quote from Standard (3.7.3 / 3):

> If a variable with automatic storage duration has initialization or a
>   destructor with side effects, it **shall not be destroyed before the end
>   of its block**, nor shall it be eliminated as an optimization even if it
>   appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may
>   be eliminated as specified in 12.8

Comment: So will it happen before or after the copy constructor ? The copy constructor is not part of my code, the compiler handles it

Comment: OopsUser, the answer by @songyuanyao provides for even the better quote. After copy constructor, if it is called at all.